# Quiz in PHP and mySQL Radio Buttons won't work

Tags: php, html, mysql, radio-button

I am trying to make a very basic quiz in PHP and mySQL.

Essentially, I have a user "Post quiz" page that will allow the user to post 3 questions with 3 options and one solution. If the user presses a radio button that has the value equal to the answer of the question (which was made in the "post quiz" page) then it will throw back text saying they got it right, other wise it will say it is wrong.

**My Problem:**

I have gotten everything to work bar one thing: *When I click one of the radio buttons in the form, they all seem to post and throw back the same condition*.

Maybe my code is just fundamentally wrong and I don't see it, but I have been at this for a week, can someone find the error for me?

Quiz Page:

**Code saying what each button is equal to,**

```
$_POST['q2o1'] = $tresult['q2_opt1'];
$_POST['q2o2'] = $tresult['q2_opt2'];
$_POST['q2o3'] = $tresult['q2_opt3'];
$q2answer = $tresult['q2answer'];
$question2 = $tresult['question2'];

$_POST['q3o1'] = $tresult['q3_opt1'];
$_POST['q3o2'] = $tresult['q3_opt2'];
$_POST['q3o3'] = $tresult['q3_opt3'];
$q1answer = $tresult['q1answer'];
$question1 = $tresult['question1'];

$_POST['q1o1'] = $tresult['q1_opt1'];
$_POST['q1o2'] = $tresult['q1_opt2'];
$_POST['q1o3'] = $tresult['q1_opt3'];
$q3answer = $tresult['q3answer'];
$question3 = $tresult['question3'];

$q1_opt1 = $_POST['q1o1'];
$q1_opt2 = $_POST['q1o2'];
$q1_opt3 = $_POST['q1o3'];
$q2_opt1 = $_POST['q2o1'];
$q2_opt2 = $_POST['q2o2'];
$q2_opt3 = $_POST['q2o3'];
$q3_opt1 = $_POST['q3o1'];
$q3_opt2 = $_POST['q3o2'];
$q3_opt3 = $_POST['q3o3'];
```

**HTML code for the radio buttons and question layout:**

```
<?php echo '<form action="quiz.php?id='.$id.'" method ="post">';?>
    <h3 id="question2"><u>Question 1: </u></h3><p> <i><?php echo $question1;?></i></p>
    <br>
    <p>A: <?php echo $q1_opt1;?></p>
    <p>B: <?php echo $q1_opt2;?></p>
    <p>C: <?php echo $q1_opt3;?></p>
    <br>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="q1o1" value =<?php echo "".$q1o1."";?> id="option1" autocomplete="off"> A
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="q1o2" value =<?php echo "".$q1o2."";?>id="option2" autocomplete="off"> B
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="q1o3" value =<?php echo "".$q1o3."";?> id="option3" autocomplete="off"> C
      </label>
    </div>
<button type="submit" name ="submitquiz" class="btn btn-success">Submit!
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>
```

**PHP saying if the POST is submitted for each button:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitquiz'])){
  if(isset($_POST['q1o1']) && $_POST['q1o1'] == $q1answer ){
    $c1= '<p><font color="#62FD01">That is the correct answer!</font></p>';
  } else{
     $w1= '<p> <font color="red">That is the wrong answer!</font></p>';
  }if(isset($_POST['q1o2']) && $_POST['q1o2'] == $q1answer ){
    $c1= '<p><font color="#62FD01">That is the correct answer!</font></p>';
  } else{
     $w1= '<p> <font color="red">That is the wrong answer!</font></p>';
  }
if(isset($_POST['q1o3']) && $_POST['q1o3'] == $q1answer ){
    $c1= '<p><font color="#62FD01">That is the correct answer!</font></p>';
  } else{
     $w1= '<p> <font color="red">That is the wrong answer!</font></p>';
  }
}
else {
  echo '<p><font color="orange">You did not answer this question</font></p>';
}
?>
<?php
if(isset($w1)){
 echo $w1; 
}else{
 echo $c1; 
}


?>
```

Comment: Just added it in there, thank you

Comment: which MySQL API are you using to connect with? You posted your HTML/PHP but no SQL.

Comment: mysqli_connect("localhost","user","password") or die(mysqli_error());
 mysqli_select_db("database") or die("Couldn't connect to the database!");

Comment: You don't seem to be assigning any variables to those which makes it all that much more harder to query. See what the manual says http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php `$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));` if that doesn't look like what you're using, then you're not connecting.

Comment: Once you've done that, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($connection))` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: also `mysqli_select_db` requires to use a parameter http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php `bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )` so that tells me you're not connecting. Just use the link I gave you above and use all 4 parameters in one http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Comment: I have the SQL query`($tresult = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($sql)) or die(mysql_error()); )` and all that, there is no error being thrown it's the fact that the display I made in the If conditions is always coming up that the user entered the wrong one

Comment: `mysqli_query()` requires DB connection be passed as the first parameter. Please read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: oh crap! you're right. Thanks!